# Почему пробел ставят " ", а не ' '?

Tags: c++, c

Есть ли рациональная причина использовать двойные, а не одинарные кавычки для вывода единственного символа в С/C++? Например, почему пробел ставят `" "`, а не `' '`?

Comment: потому, что это типы разные

Comment: @strangeqargo зачем ставить " " када можно ' '

Comment: вопрос заплюсую, потому, что человек заинтересовался, а я об этом никогда не задумывался. Аналогичный вопрос на инглеш стаке весь в плюсах. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: Уточните, кто и в каких случаях? Я, например, скорее напишу `fputc(' ', out);`, нежели `fputs(" ", out);` (хотя, вполне вероятно `puts(" ");`, а не `putchar(' ');` (из-за лени...)) / Если же Вас интересуют рациональные причины, то скорее наоборот, более рационально передавать в функцию непосредственно символ (т.е. ' '), а не его адрес (в случае " ").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. затем, что когда ты пишешь код в котором пробелы руками программиста вставляются (это как правило дебаг/хардкод), то тебе в итоге придется менять одинарные кавычки на двойные, если ты захочешь вместо внутрь `' '` что-нибудь добавить,

   warning от gcc:

   ```
   multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
       std::cout << "abc " << 'h ' << "abc";
   ```

   этот ворнинг мне нафиг не нужен, и выбирать между `"` и `'` во время дебага программы мне тоже не нужно.  А в продакшен-версии программ никакого дебаг/захардкоженного вывода не нужно тем более.
2. кроме того, "." создает литерал `.\0`, а `'.'` - `char` '.', а если мешать-туда сюда массивы символов с `\0` и без него, ты напросишься на проблемы с безопасностью и стабильностью кода.

Comment: обожаю минусаторов, которые вместо того, чтобы дать свой ответ/улучшить существующий/прокмментировать

Comment: Не минусовал, но ведь понятно же, что суть именно в том, что это `' '` и `" "` разные типы. А остальное (менять ли на двойные, если нужно внутрь `' '` что-то добавить) уже следствие.

Comment: Добавлю по поводу второго пункта в С++ есть тип std::string который не NULL-терминирован.

Answer (score 1):

**потому, что это типы разные** - Ведь вот человек сказал АБСОЛЮТНО точно.

' '  - это тип `char`, а " " это тип `char*` ! И там, где по семантике нужен тип `char` (например - `putc(' ', file);`), там используются апострофы. А там, где по семантике требуется тип `char*` (например - `fputs(" ", file);`), там используются кавычки.

Comment: `" "` это `char[2]`, а не `char*`

Comment: @ixSci я бы даже сказал, что `const char[2]`.

Comment: <это char[2], а не char*> - мне кажется. что я достаточно ясно изложил свою мысль - использование того или иного варианта зависит от семантики окружающего КОНТНЕКСТА. Если ф-ция  описана как int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);, то так и написано 'char *', а не  'char[2]'. Значит здесь надо использовать " ". Неужели здесь что-то непонятно?!

Comment: @Sergey Вы путаете истинный тип объекта с типом, к которому он неявно приводится. То что тип массива неявно приводится к типу указателя, не делает массив указателем.

Comment: **тип массива неявно приводится к типу указателя, не делает массив указателем**.  Никаких ТИПОВ данных "массив" или "структура" в языке С нет.  См. например  "Язык программирования Си" (Брайан В. Керниган, Деннис М. Ритчи), где написано в главе 2.2 : 

В Си существует всего лишь несколько базовых типов:
char - единичный байт, который может содержать один символ из допустимого
символьного набора;
int - целое, обычно отображающее естественное представление целых в машине;
float - число с плавающей точкой одинарной точности;
double - число с плавающей точкой двойной точности.

Comment: Будете спорить с авторами языка? :-)

Comment: **истинный тип объекта** - что такое ИСТИННЫЙ тип объекта (кстати, в языке С нет никаких объектов), я не знаю. Я же имел в виду следующее:

1) char s[32]; - это ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЕ массива из 32 переменных типа char. 2) s[14] - это пятнадцатый элемент массива, который имеет тип char. 3) s - это УКАЗАТЕЛЬ на на нулевой элемент (s[0]) массива s, являющийся (разумеется!) указтелем на тип char, т.е. char*. Вот и всё, что я хотел сказать...

Comment: @Sergey Так и не понял, причем тут апострофы, они тут нигде не используются, ибо есть только одинарные и двойные кавычки :)

Comment: @Sergey как это в C нет объектов? Открываем Стандарт и читаем: `object - region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values`. Там же про массивы и структуры можете прочитать.

Comment: **причем тут апострофы** - хорошо, я неправильно выразился - ОДИНАРНЫЕ КАВЫЧКИ.

Comment: **object - region of data storage** - проще говоря, кусок памяти. Я же имел в виду святую троицу С++ (наследование, инкапсуляция и полиморфизм). Я предполагаю, что "region of data storage" не обладают этими свойствами ? Кстати, авторы языка, говорят о базовых типах данных и АГРЕГАТНЫХ значениях (массивах и структурах). Не называя значения типами. Вот в строго типизированных языках (паскаль, модула, ада...), там массив - это тип. И даже массивы одной размерности и состоящие из элементов одного типа будут разными типами, если различаются количеством этих самых элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разобраться в вопросе, давайте сравним два определения переменных:

```
a) char c = ' ';
b) char const* s = " ";
```

Сначала надо уяснить, что пробел - это такой же символ, как остальные. Так же надо знать что C/C++ языки [строго типизированные](https://habrahabr.ru/post/161205/), то есть каждый тип имеет свой размер!

Теперь разберем, как будет действовать компилятор в случае `(а)`. Сначала он смотрит в левую часть этого выражения, там дана инструкция, что нужно выделить память под один символ. Затем он смотрит в правую часть и проверяет является ли это одиночным символом. Для указания одиночного символа используется `одинарная кавычка` и как раз ее он и находит первой. Он говорит: окей, всё верно, тип совпадает, надо считать один символ и проверить, не другой ли тип это и ищет закрывающую одинарную кавычку. На этом моменте остановимся подробнее: а что будет если вдруг между двумя одинарными кавычками окажется больше чем один символ? Например, так: `'аб'`. А это скажет компилятору, что произошла ошибка в коде. Видимо программист планировал что-то другое вместо одиночного символа. После проверки он найденный символ положит в память.

Теперь рассмотрим случай `(б)`. Сначала компилятор смотрит в левую часть этого выражения, там дана инструкция, что нужно выделить определенного размера память под набор символов идущих один за другим. Затем он смотрит в правую часть и проверяет является ли это набором символов. Для указания набора символов используется `двойная кавычка` и как раз ее он и находит первой. Он говорит: окей, всё верно, тип совпадает, надо считывать символы, пока они не закончатся. Признаком этого конца будет `двойная кавычка`. И по этому принципу компилятор определит размер необходимой памяти и разместит найденные символы в ней.

Из всего этого сделаем вывод, что символ и набор символов это разные типы данных, то есть имеют разные размеры. К тому же компилятор работает с ними по разному.

Comment: **нужно выделить неопределенного размера память** - на самом деле всё несколько сложнее. В этом случае компилятор выделяет 4 байта (для 32-битных систем) для УКАЗАТЕЛЯ char* в стеке блока и неопределённое количество байт в куче для ДАННЫХ, на которые ссылается указатель. Причём, если компилятор оптимизирующий, то он может вообще не выделить в куче места, если эта текстовая константа уже встречалась ранее.

Comment: **является ли это одиночным символом** Здесь тоже несколько сложнее... Напоминаю о существовании таких символов, как '\n', '\0100' и т.д.

Comment: @Sergey, вы верно говорите, но я специально усложнять не стал что бы можно было уловить саму суть процесса, к тому же не стал привязываться к конкретным размерам типов данных потому что строковые и символьное типы данных меняются от реализации к реализации и по разному реализованы в других языках, а то есть привязка к языку может пагубно влиять при переходе на другой язык.

Comment: @Sergey, `"выделяет ...и неопределённое количество байт в куче для ДАННЫХ..."` -- **неправильно**. Компилятор ничего в куче не выделяет (никогда). В данном случае он инициализирует выделенную в стеке переменную (указатель) адресом символьной константы (правой части), которую размещает в области статических данных. Точнее, константа (физически размещаемая в области команд), загружаемая в этот указатель, станет правильным адресом после работы линкера по компоновке загрузочного модуля, но это уже избыточные для данного вопроса детали.

Comment: @avp здравствуйте, с константой ясно что она будет лежать в стеке, а где будет лежать символьный массив (например `char ca[5] = "abcd";`)?

Comment: Если он описан как в примере внутри функции, то в стеке, если вне, то в секций данных (там, где все статические переменные). Кстати, он будет заполнен таким коротким содержимым ("abcd") всего парой команд  -- `movl` и `movb` (для завершающего нуля) и никакой строки "abcd" среди данных не будет (хотя, часть команды movl будет содержать эти символы). Можете сами поиграться с помощью gcc -S, gcc -c, objdump и т.п.